# Flask-Admin - Foreign Key Lookup Create if Not found

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask Admin section, which uses SQLAlchemy Models to build the forms.

I have not been able to figure out how to do an operation like "If Foreign key Not Found, insert a new record".

For instance. Take the following SQLAlchemy Models

```
class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rooms'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True,
                           autoincrement=True
                           )
    description = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(256))
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(32))
    phone_numbers = relationship('RoomPhoneNumber',
                                 backref='room')
    intercom_numbers = relationship('RoomIntercomNumber',
                                    backref='room')


class RoomPhoneNumber(Base):
    """
    A phone number assigned to a given room.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'roomextensions'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True,
                           autoincrement=True
                           )
    number = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(25))
    room_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(Room.id)
                                )
```

**Admin ModelView**

```
class RoomAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return login.current_user.is_admin
    column_auto_select_related = True
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'description')
    column_display_pk = True
    column_list = ('id', 'description', 'name', 'phone_numbers', 'intercom_numbers')
    form_columns = ['description', 'name', 'phone_numbers', 'intercom_numbers']
```

The Room Admin Model does not allow me to type in a new `RoomPhoneNumber` I would like to be able to input a Phone Number from the Room Admin model, and if it is not found, simply insert it with the current generated room ID, without having to move over to the `RoomPhoneNumberAdmin` Page

Is there a configuration in Flask-Admin I am missing, or is this a poor database design problem?

Thanks for reading, can post further information if required.

Wont allow value that does not exist
    [image]

Comment: Did you got to solve this by any chance ?

Comment: Nope, I left it un implemented but could theoretically just make a custom `Form` and implement it myself but we decided not